# screenshot a page with swf in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, screenshot, swfobject

I want to take a screenshot of a page, which contains a swf file. (I'll not be able to modify the swf)

I tried to make screenshots using **grabz.it, html2canvas**.. but it works fine if it's a page without flash.

So how do i overcome this?

How do I make it work in asp.net / c#

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A screenshot is a client operating system functionality, not a functionality of a web site (or web application, for that matter). There are multiple OSs out there (Win, Mac, Linux, iOS etc), and all handle screenshots differently.

Both tools you tried read and render HTML by themselves, and do not take actual screenshots. That's why they don't render Flash.

The only real chance you have is to find something like a Java applet, which takes a real "hard" screenshot of the user's screen, and is OS independent.

There is no way to take a screenshot with C# from ASP.NET codebehind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I completely understood what you meant! I'm working in .net environment.. is there anyway i can achieve this.. I'm also okay to purchase a tool, if that could help me.

Comment: I don't really know how. It would have to be a component running on the client machine. And then you want that screenshot posted back to the server - which I as a user would consider a security issue. 

Tell us what you want to achieve, maybe there's a different approach.

Comment: Okay. There is a page with a flash chart. On clicking a button i need to capture the image of the flash chart and serve it to the user. This functionality is handled here https://ciso.wipro.com/report/graphs/wipro.htm I need to do the same in .net

Comment: I understood your issue. 
That sample you posted does not take a "screenshot", it renders the chart in code and creates the picture. You'd have to implement that functionality in your Flash.

Comment: So true. I too knew that. But I don't have the fla of that swf. So I'll not be able to do it. I also tried decompiling the swf but no success. So all I have to do is keep a button and on clicking it generate a picture of that chart.